# \build\intermediates\res\resources-anzhi-debug-stripped.ap_' specified for property 'resourceFile' does not exist

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2, android-gradle-2.2

I updated Android Studio to version 2.0. The build failed and also takes longer than Android Studio version 1.5 to build. Every time I run my application, I clean and reload the project, but it's no use. The error message is:

> \build\intermediates\res\resources-anzhi-debug-stripped.ap_' specified
>   for property 'resourceFile' does not exist.

Comment: Same problem here...

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223254

Answer (score 87):

Having same issue ! 
So instant run is not compatible with shrinkResources

1) if use Android Studio 2.2

**shrinkResources false**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        zipAlignEnabled true
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

2) if use Android Studio 2.0

- open setting
- [image: Follow this image]
- now run your project

Comment: Thanks for the answer that Instant Run is not compatible with `shrinkResources`. But rather than disable Instant Run, for me the solution was to disable `shrinkResources` on my debug builds (you can leave it enabled for release builds), because I'd love to use the Instant Run feature

Comment: I disabled Instant run, but I get the same error in debug mode as well as release mode

Comment: Didn't work for me either.  Same `'resourceFile' does not exist.` error even with Instant run off on AS 2.2 preview 6.

Comment: shrinkResources false  is works for me thanks @parth vora

Comment: shrinkResources false isn't a solution if you want small apks.  This still exists all the way to 2.3 preview...

Comment: I want to know what could be the reason for this error occurrence.

Comment: I am using android studio 2.3.3.What should be done?

Comment: shrinkResources false still works for android 2.3.3 to fix this build error

Answer (score 55):

If you're experiencing this issue when building a `release` build, keep in mind that Android Plugin for Gradle `2.2.0` (and above) seems to have a bug with `shrinkResources`.

Downgrade `gradle` to `2.1.3` for a temporary solution:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
```

---

**EDIT:**

I reported this issue to [wojtek.kalicinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178871/wojtek-kalicinski) (Android Developer Advocate at Google).

As it turns out, `shrinkResources` works only if there is `minifyEnabled` set to `true`. `2.1.3` version of Android Plugin was just ignoring the issue (and failing to `shrinkResources` silently). `2.2.0+` is letting you know that there is something wrong with an error (which itself isn't really informative). Google might introduce a better error message for this kind of scenarios in the future.

Here's the [twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/blipinsk/status/818388317326680064):

[image]

Comment: I am having same issue with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2`, will disable `shrinkResources` for now 

Comment: `2.2.2` seems to have the same bug. You can still keep the `shrinkResources` with the temporary downgrade to `2.1.3`.

Comment: You are right. It work in my code. How do you know this? @BartekLipinski

Comment: has there been a fix launched yet? Im getting this error with `2.2.3`

Comment: @Zapnologica no, I don't think so. I still end up using `2.1.3`

Comment: The correct solution is in fact in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41361796/1178871
You have to set 
minifyEnabled true
in order for shrinkResources to work

Comment: if you are using shrinkResources true and  minifyEnabled false means you wii get this error,              minifyEnabled true then its work fine,

Comment: best answer for this issue .. wasn't aware that shrinkResources doesn't work when minifyEnabled is false .. thanks man !!

Answer (score 30):

Probably you are shrinking the resources while avoiding minifying:

```
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources true
```

If you want to shrink the resources, you have to enable minifying:

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
```

Older versions of Build Tools were ignoring this issue, but it started throwing compilation issues on Build Tools 2.2.3

More information here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-resources

Comment: I also get the same error when both `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` are set to `true`.
I might be mistaken but it seems the issue started either w/the upgrade to Gradle 2.3.0 or Android Studio 2.3.

Comment: Op, it worked for me some months ago, but probably now Build Tools changed or who know what... by the way, if you know how to fix the issue, don't hesitate to answer this question and link it to this answer :·)

Answer (score 22):

Set **shrinkResources** to `false`. It worked for me

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: Was looking for this answer for hours! Disable shrinkResources!

Comment: if shrinkresources is to be made false, then whats the point.

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer, just disable instarun and it should work. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. We could use both Instant Run and shrinkResources at the same time;
2. Please be noted that we CANNOT use Jack and shrinkResources at the same time (the same to ProGuard, minifyEnabled)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Bartek-lipinski's post, I have confirmed on my own project that downgrading Gradle plugin to v2.1.3 will solve this problem of getting `"InvalidUserDataException: File  specified for property  does not exist."`

I have filed a bug with the Android tools bugtracker [website](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227250), please upvote to get some more visibility on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, because I added in the gradle shrinkResources, remove the Ok.