# Android Studio Preview 3 error when generating release APK : release-stripped.ap_ does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk, build.gradle

I updated Android studio from **Preview 2** to **Preview 3** and now I get this error when I try to generate a release APK:

```
Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageProdRelease'.
> File '/Users/jay/repositories/test/app/build/intermediatesError:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageProdRelease'.
> File '/Users/jay/repositories/test/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-prod-release-stripped.ap_' specified for property 'resourceFile' does not exist.
```

I've read that it might be related to instant run feature so I disabled it and still the same error. And then, I tried to set `shrinkResources` attribute to `false` and then It works. BUT when I tried uploading the apk in **Google Developper Console**, it says my apk is not **Zipaligned**...

Wherever you are Google Developper, Help me out! :O

Comment: Why are you using a version of AS that's not stable to release APKs?

Comment: That's a good question actually... Because I like trouble? -___-"

Comment: No but seriously, previous preview was okay... I didn't though it could get that worse

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. "tried to set shrinkResources attribute to false and then It works. BUT when I tried uploading the apk in Google Developper Console, it says my apk is not zipaligned..."

Comment: Go back to the last stable release to create your APK...It's working that way

Comment: @Pztar don't all Android developers do that? I like AS and love to use the bleeding edge. :D

Comment: @Jaythaking try running `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies` in your AndroidStudio's Terminal. Then try generating signed APK. If it doesn't, then post your dependencies portion of your `build.gradle`

Comment: This is an issue building a release build of my app in STABLE Android Studio 2.2, just released!

Comment: This issue in the bug tracker seems to be related: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211536 It would be good to star and provide additional info for them there.

Comment: Its not really relevant anymore since there is a RC

Comment: @wojtek.kalicinski Cannot be a duplicate of a more recent post... You should have posted this on the other post

Comment: you're right, I didn't paste the correct question ID. Let me try once again: this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540676/build-intermediates-res-resources-anzhi-debug-stripped-ap-specified-for-prope

Comment: @wojtek.kalicinski You have lots of free time to dig a old topic related to a deprecated beta version of Android Studio... This isn't gonna help anyone

Comment: actually, I was asked about this on Twitter just now. There's an open bug on b.android.com and about 6 questions on SO, still relevant to the current 2.3 beta1 version of Studio. Cleaning them up and providing a correct answer would help a lot of people who are still having problems with this today.

Comment: @wojtek.kalicinski My bad...

Answer (score 5):

This problem occurs to me if I am using gradle 2.2.0-alpha3. I found a workaround to this problem. You can solve this by disabling shrinkResources and zipalign in gradle and then run zipalign using command line.

build.gradle:

```
shrinkResources false
zipAlignEnabled false
```

Run the `zipalign` command manually:

```
<your-android-sdk-path>/sdk/build-tools/23.0.3$ 
./zipalign -v 4 <your-input>.apk <your-output>.apk
```

**Edit**:

I just have a try on using older version of gradle 2.1.0, it works without this problem. zipalign problem in gradle 2.2.0-alpha3 is mentioned in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37741191/510577) as well.

Comment: I don't find it safe to generate the APK using Android Studio Preview 3... If this is hapenning, what else could go wrong? I reverted to the last stable version to generate my Signed APK and it went fine...

Comment: Yes it could be gradle's plugin version. It causes some bad UI problems as well, [such as this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=-opened&id=212804).

Comment: I'm seeing no end to problems with gradle and Android Studio. I wish the team would just simply stop developing on their product and go home.  They're making life miserable for those of us who actually have to deliver products with this crap

Comment: @CoderRoadie The problem is yours for using a beta release of a product expecting no errors. As software developers you should know what `Beta/Preview` means.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3` in the project build.gradle file which was causing me issues.

I found that I was able to successfully generate a signed APK whenever I changed it to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

According to a [Google Engineer](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223254#c6), enabling both `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` should work:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't for me.