# error while generating signed apk task app:packageRelease

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

> Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageRelease'.
>   File '/Volumes/Data/Android apps/NammaKarnataka-master/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-release-stripped.ap_' specified for property 'resourceFile' does not exist.

The following error message occurred while I tried to generate signed apk on Android studio 2.2.
 
What additional information is required in order to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540676/build-intermediates-res-resources-anzhi-debug-stripped-ap-specified-for-prope

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file ?

Comment: Thank you. setting "shrinkResources false" resolved the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\build\intermediates\res\resources-anzhi-debug-stripped.ap\_' specified for property 'resourceFile' does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540676/build-intermediates-res-resources-anzhi-debug-stripped-ap-specified-for-prope)

Answer (score 17):

Add `shrinkResources`, set to `false`, to the `release` clause:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false  //ADD THIS
        zipAlignEnabled true
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Command `flutter clean` helps me.