# Failed to read Key from Store. Cannot recover key

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting this exception while generating signed Apk i did nothing to Key store file password is also correct.If i create a new key store file.I think will not be able to upload it on play store on same app package.I cannot understand what i have to do now?

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageFreeRelease'.  Failed to
>   read key  from store  Cannot recover key

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question has already been solved in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39704089/3625488). The problem was to do with `shrinkResources`. The way to solve this is to stop Android from trying to shrink your resources. This can be done by placing the following code into your buildTypes release function:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources false
    }
}
```

Comment: The post link you shared is not related to this question.