# BUILD FAILED: configuration of task ':packageDebug' (Visual Studio)

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, geolocation, build.gradle

I've encountered this build error and don't seem to get it fixed,
the plugins I have are the default whitelist from Visual Studio,
geolocation and compat which comes with geolocation. I'm trying to build my Cordova application for Android, I've filled in the build.json correctly and my config.xml is setup as well.

**Java**: jdk1.8.0_121

```
1>  :packageDebug FAILED
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
1>  * What went wrong:
1>
1>  BUILD FAILED
1>
1>  Total time: 4.461 secs
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : A problem was found with the configuration of task ':packageDebug'.
1>  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':packageDebug'.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > File 'C:\Users\billy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\JSAPIGeolocation\JSAPIGeolocation\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_' specified for property 'resourceFile' does not exist.
1>  > File 'C:\Users\billy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\JSAPIGeolocation\JSAPIGeolocation\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_' specified for property 'resourceFile' does not exist.
1>
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:
1>  * Try:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1>  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\billy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\JSAPIGeolocation\JSAPIGeolocation\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\billy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\JSAPIGeolocation\JSAPIGeolocation\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
1>  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\billy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\JSAPIGeolocation\JSAPIGeolocation\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\billy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\JSAPIGeolocation\JSAPIGeolocation\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: **I removed the .gradle folder and it builded succesfully**
if someone's able to explain the cause I'd be happy to learn what went wrong

Comment: Take a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540676/build-intermediates-res-resources-anzhi-debug-stripped-ap-specified-for-prope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540676/build-intermediates-res-resources-anzhi-debug-stripped-ap-specified-for-prope)