# Unable to generate signed apk using shrinkResources true in release build

Tags: android, release, minify, shrinkresources

```
shrinkResources true
minifyEnabled true
```

The error is given below :

Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageRelease'.

> File 'D:\Original_ProjectBackUp\TheBarMan\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-release-stripped.ap_' specified for property 'resourceFile' does not exist.

help will be appreciated from fellow developers.

Comment: Doesn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540676/build-intermediates-res-resources-anzhi-debug-stripped-ap-specified-for-prope) help you?

Comment: it is working when shrinkResources false. but i what i want is shrinkResources true.and my instant run is also disabled.

Comment: Post all your grade and log please, I'm almost sure what can be the problem